# Trying out FCM. First steps

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying out Firebase Cloud Messaging. At this point I have read a couple of related documents, but I have nothing working.

I already set up an iOS app and a Firebase project for that purpose.

Looking at this [GitHub sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift), I have a question.

Is this line of code meant to be used as is, or is it a place holder, where I am supposed to replace *"gcm.message_id"* with some ID of mine ?
(If YES, what?)

```
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
```

More in detail, the code goes like this:

```
....
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

.......
```

And then *gcmMessageIDKey* is used later in the code, like here:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
  }
```

I am wondering, because I have already tried to include some of this code in my own app, where it seems to make sense. And then from the Firebase console Cloud Messaging, tried to send a test message.
But nothing at all is working.

Any, even small, relevant tip to move forward, will be very welcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code example.  External links can change or go stale over time, which would make this question unhelpful for others in the future.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The string is to be taken literally.  It's the key of the `userInfo` hash used to get the value of the incoming FCM message ID.

If you are not receiving a message at all, something else is wrong and has nothing to do with the value of this string.

Comment: OK. About what could be wrong, what would you check first? Knowing that I did quite a bit of reading and preparation previously (setting the  Firebase project to make that work, setting the APNs ....)

Comment: There are a LOT of questions out there on Stack Overflow about diagnosing what goes wrong with the sending of a message.  I suggest doing some research, as you're probably not encountering anything new.